# How to print two variables from two different lists with a for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

I'm trying to print two variables with a for loop from two different lists with an equal amount of values, but when the lists have more than two values I get this error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Assume both name and surname lists are the same length (eg. `name = ['m', 'y', '.', '.']` and `surname = ['n', 'a', 'm', 'e']`)

```
for x,y in name,surname:
    print(x,y)
```

My expected result is "my.." and "name" printed next to each other vertically.

Comment: Your `for` loop is iterating over a sequence with a length of two: `name` followed by `surname`.  Each of those two items gets unpacked into `x` and `y`, which fails because they contain four elements each.  To iterate the two sequences in parallel, use `zip(name, surname)`.

Comment: Go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-to-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel) post. Everything is in detail

Answer (score 1):

Use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
name = ['m', 'y', '.', '.']

surname = ['n', 'a', 'm', 'e']

for x, y in zip(name, surname):
    print(x, y)
```

Result:

```
m n
y a
. m
. e
```

Comment: can you explain why how that works? or why the way i did it doesn't

Comment: The documentation for `zip()` (linked in the answer) explains how it works thoroughly, but just playing with it ought to make it obvious in any case.